# Erro ao instalar o pacote npm do babel no meu projeto

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, babel

Estou tentando instalar o pacote do babel em meu projeto. Mas ao executar o comando: *npm install --save-dev babel-cli*, ocorre um erro na instalação do *tar.unpack*. Veja na imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ja tentei atualizar o npm, atualizar o nodejs e limpar o cache. Mas nada disso resolveu. Se alguém ai ja tiver passado por isso e puder me ajudar eu ficarei grato!

Comment: Já testaste instalar globalmente? com `-g`?

Comment: @Sergio, acabei descobrindo o erro. Eu estava tentando instalar pelo prompt do git e parece que o correto é usar o prompt do nodejs. ao fazer pelo prompt do nodejs deu certo. Mas valeu pela dica! ;)

Comment: Ok, nesse caso coloca uma resposta. Pode ser util a mais gente.

Comment: Beleza! Vou postar!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolvido o problema! Eu estava tentando fazer a instalação do pacote do Babel pelo prompt do git. E parece que por isso não deu certo.

Mas ao refazer o mesmo processo usando o prompt do Nodejs deu certo.

Caso alguém tenha esse problema fica a dica! ;)